# Open Source alternative for Confluent Kafka Connect MQTT Source and Sink connectors

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I want to connect by MQTT broker to Apache Kafka (non enterprise version and no confluent kafka managed service used).

I was using Confluent's Kafka Connect MQTT source and sink but I realized it comes with a trial period of 30 days after which it requires a license.

Are there any other open source / free options to use as a bidirectional bridge between Apache Kafka and mqtt broker.

Comment: This is another open source option for mqtt source and sink connector 
https://github.com/johanvandevenne/kafka-connect-mqtt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Lenses' MQTT Source Connector](https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/source/mqtt.html):

> A Connector to read events from MQTT and push them to Kafka. The
>   connector subscribes to the specified topics and and streams the
>   records to Kafka.

Lenses also offer [MQTT Sink Connector](https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/mqtt.html) for streaming records from Kafka to a target system.

---

Both connectors require the following:

- Apache Kafka 0.11.x of above
- Kafka Connect 2.x or above
- Mqtt server
- Java 1.8

Comment: The question was "are there any other open source /free options..."  so he's not looking to replace one commercial license for another.  Lenses is a commercial offering that requires a license.

Comment: @RickO'Shea Lenses has also open source offerings.

Comment: I could not find the licence info on said page. Which licence is the MQTT connector under, and is it free beer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any detailed code examples available, just my 2 cents:

You have to build your own bridge, i.e. MQTT <-> Kafka (pub/sub <-> producer/consumer).

- On the MQTT side IMHO the Eclipse PAHO client looks is pretty nice. Have a look at this howto: https://www.baeldung.com/java-mqtt-client.
- On the Kafka a rather simple implementation with a producer and a consumer should be pretty easy. Things get complicated if you want to take the MQTT QoS into account (i.e. At most once (0), At least once (1), Exactly once (2)). At least once you can manage by having the offset commit under control and keeping an eye on the processing state of MQTT<->Kafka messages, for exactly once have a look at [Kafka Transactions](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/).